# using BeginVerifyPin and EndVerifyPin methods in a UCMA workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, lync-2010, ucma

need a simple example of how to call **ApplicationPinServices BeginVerifyPin and EndVerifyPin** methods from inside a UCMA workflow to verify user pin number...
**ApplicationPinServices** has an internal constructor and i can't find a way to instantiate it in order to call the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to verify the pin by casting the conversation endpoint to **ApplicationEndpoint** which contains a reference to PinServices Class:

```
var localEndPoint = this.communicationsSequenceActivity1.CallProvider.Call.Conversation.Endpoint as ApplicationEndpoint;

PinVerificationResult result = localEndPoint.PinServices.EndVerifyPin
                                     (localEndPoint.PinServices.BeginVerifyPin(
                                                        userSIP, selectedPin, null, null, null));
```